# Is it possible to pass "this.state" object from child to parent component using function parameters?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am quite new to react and working on sending data from child component to parent component by passing function in parent component as a **props** to child. When I pass string as a function parameter it works fine, but when I pass **this.state** as a function parameter to parent component it logs empty object.

Here is the code for App.js (Parent) Component

```
class App extends Component {
  onClick = (vals) =>{
   console.log(`${"App Components"} ${vals}`)
     }
  render() {


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form fetchValue={(vals) => this.onClick(vals)}>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the function I'm accessing in Form.js (Child) Component as a **props** whenever **"onClickButton"** is called

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            user : "Enter User Name",
            password: "Enter Your Password",
            email: "enter your e-mail"
        }
    }

    onUserValueChnage = (e) => {
        this.setState({
          user: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onPassValueChnage = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onEValueChnage = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value
        }) 
    }

    onClickButton = (e) => {
        console.log(this.state)
        this.props.on(this.state)
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onClickButton}>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.user} onChange= {this.onUserValueChnage} />
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onPassValueChnage}/>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEValueChnage}/>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>  
            </div>         
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

I've passed **this.state** as a parameter to App Component and it logs empty object.

The question I'm trying to ask is, is it possible to pass object as function parameter to parent component?

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Welcome Abdul to Stackoverflow. I can sorta guess what's going on but would need code as @Train suggested. And as a new user, please refer to [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) documentation on creating an example or asking questions on SO.

Comment: @Train I've edited my question with some code.

Comment: @SungM.Kim updated my question with some code. And thank you for the suggestion about "Asking questions "

Comment: We need to see the whole react component that contains `onClickButton`.

Comment: @technogeek1995 I've updated the question with complete code

Comment: Show some love add more up votes to his question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having appears to be as a result of the `onClickButton` in the child component. You're calling `this.props.on`. However, the function you're passing in from the parent component's render function is called `fetchValue`. Instead, in `onClickButton` in your child component, you should call `this.props.fetchValue`. I also am performing a spread operation when passing state. It is bad to open up the potential to mutate state directly.

```
onClickButton = (e) => {
  console.log(this.state)
  this.props.fetchValue({ ...this.state})
  e.preventDefault()
 }
```

Optionally, you can also change your parent component to refer directly to the reference of the function, rather than an anonymous function.

```
<Form fetchValue={this.onClick} />
```

**Updated Answer:**

You'll need to change it to this if you want to see your value. When you do string interpolation and try to print an object, it will output `[object, object]` because it isn't a string. You'd need to wrap your variable with `JSON.stringify(value)` if you want it to print the object as a string when doing string interpolation. However, you could also update `onClick` in your `App` Component to be something like this, and it should print the object like you're expecting.

```
onClick = (value) =>{
  console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. I've made the changes and corrected the function in the child component, but it still logs the empty object.

the value in console is [object Object]

Comment: @AbdulR. checkout my updated answer in regards to your comment

Comment: It's working, and now I've understand. We can pass the state objects but we must have to Stringify it to print.

Thank you so Much

Comment: Yes if you're doing `My Object ${JSON.stringify(value)}`, you must use `JSON.stringify()`. Otherwise, you can just do `console.log(value)` and it will print

Answer (score 1):

In your parent:

```
const onChildClicked = name => console.log(name)

return <Child onClickChild={onChildClicked} />
```

In `Child`:

```
return <div id='hey' onClick={e => props.onChildClicked(e.target)}
```

Your console should show : `hey`